# Why is a TimeoutError not being raised in concurrent.futures.Future instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I'm basing this off of the sample from https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#id1.

I've update the following:
`data = future.result()`
to this:
`data = future.result(timeout=0.1)`

The doc for `concurrent.futures.Future.result` states:

> If the call hasn’t completed in timeout seconds, then a TimeoutError will be raised. timeout can be an int or float

*(I know there is a timeout on the request, for 60, but in my real code I'm performing a different action that doesn't use a urllib request)*

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            # The below timeout isn't raising the TimeoutError.
            data = future.result(timeout=0.01)
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

`TimeoutError` is raised if I set it on the call to `as_completed`, but I need to set the timeout on a per Future basis, not all of them as a whole.

---

### Update

Thanks @jme, that works with a single Future, but not with multiples using the below. Do I need to `yield` at the beginning of the functions to allow the build-up of the `futures` dict? From the docs it sounds like the calls to `submit` shouldn't block.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import sys

def wait():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 42

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    waits = [wait, wait]
    futures = {executor.submit(w): w for w in waits}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        try:
            future.result(timeout=1)
        except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
            print("Too long!")
            sys.stdout.flush()

print(future.result())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the call to `concurrent.futures.as_completed()`.

If I replace that with just a `for` loop, everything seems to work:

```
for wait, future in [(w, executor.submit(w)) for w in waits]:
    ...
```

I misinterpreted the doc for `as_completed` which states:

> ...yields futures as they **complete** (finished or were cancelled)...

`as_completed` will handle timeouts but as a whole, not on a per future basis.

Comment: Posting the complete solution would have been helpful

Answer (score 2):

The exception *is* being raised in the main thread, you just aren't seeing it because `stdout` hasn't been flushed. Try for example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import sys

def wait():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 42

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(wait)
    try:
        future.result(timeout=1)
    except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
        print("Too long!")
        sys.stdout.flush()

print(future.result())
```

Run this and you'll see "Too long!" appear after one second, but the interpreter will wait an additional four seconds for the threads to finish executing. Then you'll see `42` -- the result of `wait()` -- appear.

What does this mean? Setting a timeout doesn't kill the thread, and that's actually a good thing. What if the thread is holding a lock? If we kill it abruptly, that lock is never freed. No, it's much better to let the thread handle its own demise. Likewise, the purpose of `future.cancel` is to prevent a thread from starting, not to kill it.